# How to make custom tab visible to only one user in lightning?

Tags: lightning, tab

I have created a custom tab "Pricing Approval" beside "Details" tab on the record page of opportunity. I want to visible this tab to only User. Please suggest any salesforce out of box functionality for this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hey This can be easily achieved using salesforce out of the box "[Set Component Visibility Feature](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_page_components_visibility.htm&type=5)"

- Navigate to the record where the tab should be made available conditionally (In this case "Pricing Approval")
- On the top Right "Click on the Gear Icon and choose "Edit Page"
- Click on the tab that has to be conditionally rendered (In this case "Pricing Approval" tab)
- Click on the tab content and set the component visibility on the bottom right (Advanced -- Field User> Username EQUALS

Image for Reference

[image]

Comment: Hi Abhijith, Thanks for the reply. But in this way we can only hide content under Tab not tab itself.

Comment: Yep true!! if you trying to hide the tab completely I don't think there is way there is an idea posted here: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003dfmQAA

However, you can still hide the entire tab by creating a replica of the entire Page without "Pricing Approval" Tab and conditionally showing the page only to the specified user... Also, the page with "Pricing Approval" Tab should also be made conditonally available to all users except the one user 

Comment: Thanks, Abhijit this way we can do this. thanks again!

Comment: Glad could help! Please don't forget to mark this answer if it helped you 